# How to return a value of unknown type?

Tags: c#

I have a *very* abstract problem ahead of me.

I have a class that has a public property of type `Dictionary<string, object>` the job of this dictionary is to hold custom user settings and their values.

There are no constraints on the settings but generally they are similar to:

"Brightness", 100

"Connection, "TCP"

So when I instantiate this class its dictionary property will be filled with the names of the settings and their corresponding values.

The problem is retrieving a value.

Since the values can be ints, strings, etc. they are stored as an `object` in the dictionary but I need to retrieve them as a concrete type.

While I can use `dict["Brightness"].GetType()` to find out what the type or use pattern matching I am having trouble figuring out what method return type to use.

I thought that, maybe, I can use a separate "result" property for each type and based on the value's type assign the corresponding value to the correct property, so like if the "Brightness" is 100, then have a method that tests the type of the value of "Brightness" and upon seeing it is int do something like

```
int resultInt;
resultInt = (int)dict["Brightness"];
```

But something tells me this is ugly and there is a better way.

Furthermore this is not threadsafe.

**Additional information on the program's purpose:**

The program's idea is to be able to, basically, store a bunch of settings and their values for different systems. They are always in a key-value relationship, keys are unique and values can be anything. They can be strings, ints, floats, decimal, etc. The purpose of the program is user customisation, in a way.

What I mean by this is - the user enters what settings he wants stored. What he enters becomes the full list of possible settings that the program will work with. He then enters values for these settings for each system or "device" that he has. So, for example, he says "I have a computer and a smartphone". Enters the settings "Brightness" and "CPU" into the program. Now the program knows all systems he configures will have these two settings with possibly different values associated with them.

So then the user can say "I want my smartphone screen brightness to be 80%." so he enters the int "80" as the value of "Brightness" for the entry that will correspond to his smartphone. Similarly he can enter a different value for his home computer.

Bottom line I never know what types will need to be stored.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be storing objects of different type in the same dictionary?

Comment: Seems like you should some kind of deserilizer, e.g. JSON, XML or whatever. Anyway you should not use a **single** datastructure for **different** things.

Comment: Learn how to use Generics, this is precisely what they're for.

Comment: @MikeZ Not really. If the types don´t have anything in common, there´s simply nothing *generic* here.

Comment: Maybe look at the `SqlDataReader` class which has the same issue. It has methods that just return an object but also methods for each base type that return a typed result.

Comment: This might be an X-Y problem. You should elaborate on the underlying strategy so people can help you out with a better strategy. In either case, do you deduce the type at run time or it is known at compile time? If it is not known at compile time, then you may be re-inventing the serialization and de-serialization problem. You can always use dynamic as return type, if that is truly your situation

Comment: @DavidG, I can't think of a better way, except having a separate dictionary for every type there is, as I don't know what types will need to be stored. Refer to my edit for more information.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, but then you can use a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55103638/1663001) below that has type safety.

Comment: If you don´t know the types at **compile-time**, then there is no way to have a **type-save** solution. Having said this your solution is as good or as bad as all provided answers here that use `dynamic` or `Dictionary`.

Comment: If the values are user entered, are they entered into the system as a string? Can the values be anything other than simple types (string, decimal, and other native types)? If that is the case, why not use a `Type.Parse` call to return the proper type?  You can store an `enum` type_id indicator for the value, if that is known while entering

Comment: I think you have a really nasty problem here if you don't know the types until runtime, there is almost certainly a code smell here.

Comment: @DavidG, I'm open to all suggestions. But the scope is - unkown users add unknown strings that have corresponding unknown values. And the program must be able to get them internally as known types.

Comment: If you have absolutely no idea on the actual types you can of course use `object` or even `dynamic`. However be aware that you can´t do much with those objects, unless you cast them to their actual type. Handling `object` all the way down in your API is brittle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't know at compile time what type is in your dictionary, you can use the `dynamic` tag (reworking the example of Patrick):

```cs
public dynamic GetValueOrDefault(string key)
{
    if (this.dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out object o))
    {
        return o;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Use case:

```cs
int val;

val = dict.GetValueOrDefault("Brightness");
```

Comment: What if "Brightness" isn't an int? Maybe I communicated poorly that I do not know what types it will be. Refer to my edit for more information.

Comment: Hmm, I just saw your edit and I think that it's impossible to do - some libraries use getters like `GetString`, `GetInt32`, etc... You should do your own class with specifications like those.

Comment: @J.Doe Again: there is no way for the **compiler** to guess what types you provide at **runtime**. You will never have any type-safety.

Comment: Wait... I got it - I can use this solution, I'll just add a check that tries to convert it and gives an error if it fails. That should work, right? @HimBromBeere

Comment: @J.Doe Sure, it works at **runtime**. So if anyone writes `(string)dict["Brightness"]` he/she will only notice that if the code is actually **executed**.

Comment: This is worse than the other answers in my opinion, there is absolutely no need to use `dynamic`, it's a horrible hack that can cause runtime exceptions. Also, dynamic is terribly slow to use.

Comment: @DavidG, but it fits best my actual question "How to return a value of unkown type". All the other answers require that I know the type beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated:** As per the comments and your clarification: there is no way to write your code type-safe when you don't know the type on beforehand. There is no use in it.

So you have to keep using reflection or your own way of registering the type metadata (an enum or class containing some useful information on its type).

You can use your own metadata as decribed above to build your UI, do data validation and required casting in specific cases.

---

**Old and less relevant:** If you know the type on compile time, you could use generics to make it look a little more streamlined:

```
public T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string key)
{
    if (this.dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out object o))
    {
        return (T)(object)o;
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

For sure you have to check if your design makes sense, but I can't judge that right now from what you have written.

Comment: I prefer to specify the default value as a parameter, but it works this way too.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. Letting it just fail is also an option, or return the value as out, just as `TryGetValue` does. This was just the first thing that popped into mind. @DavidG

Comment: "then have a method that tests the type of the value of "Brightness" and upon seeing it is int do something like" tells me OP does **not** know the type at compile-time.

Comment: If I see `(int)dict["Brightness"]`, I think OP does. But lets see OP on this @HimBromBeere

Comment: This is no different than the OP's code which casts it, other than that this code gives the false impression that it's actually okay to use any type, when in fact this code will fail if the caller doesn't use the correct type.

Comment: This looks nicer than what I envisioned but I think @Servy is right. Refer to my edit for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a format deserializer (e.g JSON / XML) to read an input and deserialize it to a given structure.

In your case you would define a class with the specific fields that you expect from this input file. 
(This example is using JSON but the principles are the same regardless of the notation format)

```
public class Settings {

    public int Brightness { get; set; }

    public string Connection { get; set; }

}
```

And then you would deserialize like so

```
var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(fileInput)
```

The deserializer knows the type because you have defined it. (Note each field does not need to exist for the type to be created.)

Comment: The `JsonProperty` attributes are redundant here.

Comment: Best solution IMHO.

Comment: @DavidG I would disagree, if he wants to refactor the names then the structure still works.

Comment: Then add the attributes later. They add zero value at the start.

Comment: Thanks, but, if I am not mistaken, this doesn't work if I don't know what type the properties need be, correct? Refer to my edit for more information.

Comment: Then in that case you cant use `(int)dict["Brightness"];` as you wont know about `"Brightness"`. If you don't know the fields then you cant know the values, and if you don't know the values then you cant know what to cast them to. (Unless you get the user to specify the type).

Answer (score 0):

> But something tells me this is ugly and there is a better way.

I completely agree your assumption.

It seems like you actually have some knowledge about the actual types but just want a single place to de-serialize those information. Assuming this having a **single** datastructure that represents **completely unreleated** things is a bad idea, as you end up with some weird casting- and typechecking-solution-nightmare. In particular you could easily write code that will fail at runtime:

```
var a = (int)dict["Connection"];
```

Instead you should have a statically typed datatype that represents those information. Create a class that has all those attributes and use some serializer-library, such as [Newtonsofts JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to de-serialize the attributes into that datastructure.

```
class Settings
{
    public int Brightness { get; set; }
    public string Connection { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can easily de-serialize your settings:

```
var setting = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(myJson)
```

and have completely deterministic behaviour:

```
var b = setting.Brightness; // no casting to int neccessary
```

Comment: Thanks, but the whole problem is I never know what types these properties will be. I don't even know what properties there will be, the ones I have given are an example. Refer to my edit for more information.